# What is this syntax "myMethod<S, R>"?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Going over this project I'm working on, encountered this bit of code that I don't really understand...

`_monitor.Run(RaiseEvent, sender, args);` Go To Definition on `Run` takes me to this:

```
    public void Run<S, R>(Action<S, R> action, S s, R t)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_sync, wait))
        {
            try
            {
                action(s, t);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandlers.LogVerbose("UI.Shell", "Failed to Enter Event (1)", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!_isDisposing)
                    Monitor.Exit(_sync);
            }
        }
    }
```

There's another overload for `Run` that simply has just  and only the first two arguments from the sample there.

What is the `<S, R>` in the method name and `Action` parameter? I'm inferring that they are some sort of generic types that allow for an "ambiguous" parameter (`s` and `t`) but I don't see where / how S or R are getting set.

Comment: [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) --

Comment: Given that you suspect these are generics, why didn't you read your text book, or even the docs on MSDN? Asking Qs on basic language features is not how to learn them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't know the term, I guess. Also at work I don't have books on hand.

Comment: Clearly you do know the term. It's right there in the question. We like to help, but we prefer to help those that try to help themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a generic method, where `S` and `R` are defined by the calling code. So for your posted example, `S` is the type of `sender` (most likely `object`) and `R` is the type of `args` (most likey `EventArgs`).

The `Action<S, R>` is a delegate that accepts two parameters, but does not return anything. A delegate that needs to return a value is `Func<T, TResult>`, where `TResult` is the type of the return value.